# Significant performance difference between a local mysql server and a production mysql server

Tags: mysql, performance

I am the new maintainer of an application running in production MySQL. The previous maintainer has gone leaving few documentation, and is not contactable.

The  issue I face is that the following request takes around 10 seconds to execute:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE (`active` = TRUE AND `deleted_at` IS NULL);
```

There are about 170,000 records in the users table and no indexes.

The EXPLAIN command on this request:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE (`active` = TRUE AND `deleted_at` IS NULL);
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 145407 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

Current site owner (non technical person) told me that performances dropped suddenly 2 weeks ago. So before trying to add indexes, I have dumped the production db into my local MySQL server. The e same requests takes only 4 seconds locally.

I'm quite surprised by this difference, and I'm wondering if it's possible that some issue at the OS or MySQL server might explain it? Is it worth investigating in this way? If so how? If not, are such performance "normal" for such a query without indexes (I have limited experienced about SQL performance)?

On the server:

```
$ mysql -u root --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.44, for unknown-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 5.4 (Final)
```

Local machine:

```
$ $ mysql -u root --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.42, for apple-darwin10.2.0 (i386) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Thanks!

EDIT for Traroth:

- RAM: 4GB on production, 2GB on local machine
- request caching: indeed on local machine subsequent requests are much more quicker, on production it's getting better also but still too slow (around 5 seconds in best case). Do you think that's normal?
- both DB use InnoDB
- filesystem: production box is a VPS, 'simfs' shows up when I look up for the filesystem

Comment: Which amount of RAM do you have on both systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to build an index on column `active, and deleted_at`

I would think `delete_at is null` is just ...

you might want to convert it to `smallint`, default 0 (represent is null)

If you doing bulk deletion, `optimize table your_table;` will compress the data for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Possible differences:

- if you run the same query multiple times, MySQL will cache the results, so every time you run it after the first time, as long the results are in the cache, it will be very quick.
- Could be a difference of filesystems. Your Linux is probably running a ext3 or ext4 fs, and your Mac an HFSX fs. You should try to run your backup on a linux box.
- Are you using the same database engine on both versions of your db? Speed can be very different depending on which you are using (InnoDB, MyISAM and so on)

Comment: Thanks Traroth! I've edit my question to add those information.

Answer (score 0):

The machines differ in many respects (CPU count, CPU speed, RAM amount, RAM speed, disk speed (access time and throughput), disk distribution, and of course, system load. So you should not expect performance to be the same.